# msgbox that disappears automatically after certain time

Tags: vb.net, msgbox

Is there any type of `msgbox` in vb.net that gives a message and it disappears automatically after a certain time?
Or is there any method to hide the `msgbox`, without user's clicking OK?

Comment: Maybe you should implement your own message box and get its code to fade it off after sometime (it's easy to do that). I don't think messageboxes have that feature.

Comment: could you plesee give me a hint how to do it?

Comment: I guess that answer by AJ does it. Just remember to show the form with `.showDialog()`

Answer (score 10):

You Can use

**CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("Welcome", 1, "Title")**

this msgbox will close automatically after 1 second

Comment: Is there any way to have this object's methods auto-completed by Intellisense? Must it be Casted to some type?

Comment: Is there a way to make it appear on top of all other windows? Or to specify a position?

Comment: Just to add if you wanted to use this in VBA use `call` before the entire line

Comment: CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("YOU ARE EARLY", 2, MsgBox_String, MsgBoxStyle.Critical) we can also add style to box.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think there's a built-in framework control that will do this for you.  However, you could easily do this with a custom-built form that fires a timer in it's `Load` event.  Then, when the set amount of time has passed, in the timer `Elapsed` event, you can simply close the form.

Answer (score 2):

Linendra Soni's answer is good, but it may or may not work in the newer versions of Windows and/or Excel.

**This works perfectly in the newer versions:**

```
Function MessageTimeOut(sMessage As String, sTitle As String, iSeconds As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Shell
    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Shell.Run "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.shell"").Popup(""" & sMessage & """," & iSeconds & ",""" & sTitle & """))"
    MessageTimeOut = True
End Function
```

**Use it like this:**

```
Sub Example()
    Dim chk As Boolean
    chk = MessageTimeOut("Hello!", "Example Sub", 1) 'if chk returned FALSE that means the function was not executed successfully
End Sub
```

**or**

```
Sub Example()
    Call MessageTimeOut("Hello!", "Example Sub", 1) 'you don't need to get the output of the function
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Ibo, I just used your code. How do I add new line? I tried vbNewLine and vbCrLf but they did not work.

Comment: str=“line1”  &  vbneline & “line2”, replace “Hello!” with str

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer or some type of delay/sleep and after time expires run

```
SendKeys.Send("~")
```

This is the same has hitting the ENTER key.

You may need to make it proceed it by activating the msgbox window again.

Comment: Could you add a little bit more to your answer, or include some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answers, this is what I came with, working nicely in simple cases, allowing to use all MsgBox features directly:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module FormUtils
    Private sAutoClosed As Boolean

    Private Sub CloseMsgBoxDelay(ByVal data As Object)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(CInt(data))
        SendKeys.SendWait("~")
        sAutoClosed = True
    End Sub

    Public Function MsgBoxDelayClose(prompt As Object, ByVal delay As Integer, Optional delayedResult As MsgBoxResult = MsgBoxResult.Ok, Optional buttons As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.ApplicationModal, Optional title As Object = Nothing) As MsgBoxResult
        Dim t As Thread

        If delay > 0 Then
            sAutoClosed = False
            t = New Thread(AddressOf CloseMsgBoxDelay)
            t.Start(delay)

            MsgBoxDelayClose = MsgBox(prompt, buttons, title)
            If sAutoClosed Then
                MsgBoxDelayClose = delayedResult
            Else
                t.Abort()
            End If
        Else
            MsgBoxDelayClose = MsgBox(prompt, buttons, title)
        End If

    End Function
End Module
```

PS: You must add this to yourApp.config file:

`<appSettings>
    <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>
</appSettings>`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a tool such as that. But I think you can do that with follow this steps;

1. Create an instance of Form element, and design it like a messagebox.
2. In Form load event, get the system time or start the timer with interval value.
3. This timer tick how many seconds you want then call the Form Close event.

P.S : If I'm wrong, I'm sorry. I only try to solve something, maybe there is a better way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a Timer to your form.
    'Timer to autoclose after 100 ms
     Dim seconds As Integer = 100

```
'Existing code....
 Timer1.Start()
 MessageBox.Show("Window Timed Out", "TimeOut")
 Me.Close()

'Tick Event Code
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
             System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    seconds = seconds - 1
    If seconds < 1 Then`    
       Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some code to show file updated time and close message box within 3 sec.
Please see below.
I hope that this code can support this topic.

```
    Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SplashUserForm.Show
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    last_update = "Last updated : " & Format(FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName), "ddd dd/mm/yy hh:mm ampm")

    'Close message after time if no action!
    Dim myTimedBox As Object
    Dim boxTime%, myExpired%, myOK%, myQuestBox%

    'Access timed message box.
    Set myTimedBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    boxTime = 3


    'User Selected "OK."
    If myQuestBox = 1 Then
    'Add any code in place of code below for this condition!
        myOK = myTimedBox.Popup(last_update & vbCr & "Do nothing and this message will close in 3 seconds.", _
        boxTime, "You Took Action!", vbOKOnly)

    Else

    'User took no Action!
        myExpired = myTimedBox.Popup(last_update & vbCr & "Do nothing and this message will close in 3 seconds.", _
        boxTime, "No Action Taken!", vbOKOnly)
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the way

http://www.vbforums.com/showpost.php?p=3745046&postcount=5

Comment: We discouraged answers that composed of links only, please explain it briefly. In the case that that link has been removed your answer will just become nonsense.